# How to check the value returned by a gRPC endpoint?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I am writing an application in Go that implements a gRPC API.

Here is the ProtoBuff specification that describes my endpoint's response message:

```
rpc MyEndpoint(RequestMessage) returns (ResponseMessage) {
  option (google.api.http) = {
    post: "/MyEndpoint"
    body: "*"
  };
}

message ResponseMessage {
  message SubMessage {
    int32 a = 1;
    map<string, int32> b = 2;
  }
  string c = 1;
  map<string, SubMessage> d = 2;
}
```

I am writing a test case to verify the response from the endpoint is what I expected it to be.
Here is my code to do that:

```
expectedResponse := ResponseMessage{
    C: "string1",
    D: map[string]*ResponseMessage_SubMessage{
        "string2": &ResponseMessage_SubMessage{
            A: 1,
            B: map[string]int32{
                "string3": 2,
            },
        },
    },
}
fmt.Println("responseFromEndpoint =  ", responseFromEndpoint)
fmt.Println("expectedResponse     =  ", expectedResponse)
assert.Equal(t, expectedResponse, responseFromEndpoint) // This is line #230 in file my_test_file.go
```

When I run this test-case, I get this output:

```
responseFromEndpoint = map[c:string1 d:map[string2:map[a:1 b:map[string3:2]]]]
expectedResponse     = {{{} [] [] <nil>} 0 [] string1 map[string2:a:1  b:{key:"string3"  value:2}]}
```

And the test case fails like this:

```
MyTestClass/MyTestCase: my_test_file.go:230:
        Error Trace:    my_test_file.go:230
        Error:          Not equal:
                        expected: ResponseMessage(ResponseMessage{state:impl.MessageState{NoUnkeyedLiterals:pragma.NoUnkeyedLiterals{}, DoNotCompare:pragma.DoNotCompare{}, DoNotCopy:pragma.DoNotCopy{}, atomicMessageInfo:(*impl.MessageInfo)(nil)}, sizeCache:0, unknownFields:[]uint8(nil), Name:"string1", SubMessages:map[string]*ResponseMessage_SubMessage{"string2":(*ResponseMessage_SubMessage)(0xc000098180)}})
                        actual  : map[string]interface {}(map[string]interface {}{"c":"string1", "d":map[string]interface {}{"string2":map[string]interface {}{"a":1, "b":map[string]interface {}{"string3":2}}}})
```

How can I modify my test case so that I can ensure the endpoint responded with the data that I expected it to?

Comment: It looks like the response from endpoint is a map, not a struct

Comment: @BurakSerdar ok. How can check it's value??

Comment: Whatever `MyEndpoint` you are calling is not returning what I would expect based on the proto file you included ([sample](https://play.golang.org/p/5mmwdtB6uLy)).  Try deleting the generated files and rerunning `protoc`. Alternatively post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what you are doing in full.  Also note that doing a direct comparison will not work (unless your `assert.Equal` has special handling - see [protocmp](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/testing/protocmp#Transform)).